# Android how can i get the textview string value from list view

Tags: android

i want the textview value from the list but it always gives the last value not from the selected position

```
public class myListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyOrderData> implements OnClickListener  {

    public myListAdapter() {

        super(context, R.layout.myorder_list_row, myorderlist);

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View itemView = convertView;
        if (itemView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myorder_list_row, null);
        }

        // /////
        MyOrderData currentdata = myorderlist.get(position);

        // TextView tvordernu, tvpackage, tvtotalgarment, tvorderdate,
        // tvpickupdate, tvpickuptime, tvstatus;

        txt_ticketno = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_ticket_number);
        txt_raise_date = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_raise_date);
        txt_service = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_service);
        txt_time = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_time);
        txt_status = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_status);
        txt_view = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_view);




        txt_ticketno.setText("" + currentdata.get_ticketnum());
        txt_raise_date.setText("" + currentdata.get_deliverdate());
        txt_service.setText("" + currentdata.get_service());
        txt_time.setText("" + currentdata.get_date());
        txt_status.setText("" + currentdata.get_status());




        txt_ticketno.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                Intent refresh = new Intent(context, Activity_ticket_details.class);



                refresh.putExtra("fname",""+txt_ticketno.getText().toString());



                context.startActivity(refresh);

            }
        });


        return itemView;



    }
```

i need the text value

Answer (score 1):

You should not call click listeners outside Activities. What you want to do is to implement an OnItemClickListener in your activity; you will get (among other parameters) the position of the clicked view, and can retrieve from the adapter the correspondent MyOrderData object from which you can get the String you want.

```
ListView yourList = (ListView) findViewById(...);
yourList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
          Object listItem = list.getItemAtPosition(position);
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i just made a mistake istead of textview i can use below code

refresh.putExtra("fname",""+currentdata.get_ticketnum().toString());